# Is there an alternative to grid fill if vertices are not equal

Tags: modeling, vertices

I’m working on a race car model i want to fill the nose and for it to round nicely but i don’t think the vertices are even i would grid fill but it is not an option because of that is there an alternative or do i painfully have to plot every vertex and reposition them[image]
[image]